# Find automatically cancelled subscriptions in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have setup my Stripe subscriptions to be automatically cancelled after 3 failed payment attempts.

1) Is there a way to tell from the subscription deleted webhook whether the subscription was deleted by stripe because of failed payment attempts OR deleted by us because of an API request we made to cancel it?

2) Can I use the api or dashboard to find a few sample subscriptions that were automatically cancelled by Stripe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, by checking the [event object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object)'s [`request`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object-request) attribute. If the event is the consequence of an API request, `request` will have a non-null value. If the event is the consequence of an automatic action by Stripe, then `request` will be null.

So for [`customer.subscription.deleted`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-customer.subscription.deleted) events, `request` will be non-null if you used the API to [cancel the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription), and null if the subscription was automatically canceled after too many failed payments.

2) Not via the dashboard, but using the API, you could [list all events](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_events) with [`type`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_events-type) set to `customer.subscription.deleted`, then filter the results to keep only events with `request=null`.

Keep in mind that all "list" calls only return a finite number of resources per call (10 by default, up to 100 with the [`limit`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pagination-limit) parameter). You might need to use issue several calls with [pagination parameters](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pagination) in order to retrieve the entire list. Most of Stripe's official language libraries support an [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api#auto-pagination) feature to make this process easier.